# extjs grid panel

Tags: extjs

How can we determine if a column is checked or unchecked in column menu header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to check if a particular column is hidden, as opposed to whether the menu is checked? If so:

`grid.getColumnModel().isHidden(index);`

Comment: Can I know how can i check if a particular column has hideable option or not?

Comment: my question was how do we check if a column has hideable option or not?